# How to add proxy to BoxApiConnection in box java sdk?

Tags: java, proxy, sdk, box

I need to set proxy in boxapiconnection. But could not get any reference code to use.Can anyone give me solution?

Answer (score 2):

BoxAPIConnection api = new BoxAPIConnection(code);

```
    Proxy proxy = null;
    try {
        proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName("proxy URL"), PortNo));
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    api.setProxy(proxy);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection which does not have a proxy. I created the below code to overcome the issue which gives token which auto-refreshes after expiry time:

```
import com.box.sdk.BoxConfig;
import com.box.sdk.BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection;
import com.box.sdk.DeveloperEditionEntityType;
import com.box.sdk.IAccessTokenCache;
import com.eclipsesource.json.JsonObject;

import java.net.Proxy;

public class MyBoxAPIConnection extends BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection {

private IAccessTokenCache accessTokenCache;
private String entityID;
private DeveloperEditionEntityType entityType;

public MyBoxAPIConnection(BoxConfig boxConfig, IAccessTokenCache accessTokenCache, Proxy proxy) {
    this(boxConfig.getEnterpriseId(), DeveloperEditionEntityType.ENTERPRISE, boxConfig, accessTokenCache);
    this.setProxy(proxy);
    this.tryRestoreUsingAccessTokenCache();
}

public MyBoxAPIConnection(String entityId, DeveloperEditionEntityType entityType, BoxConfig boxConfig,
        IAccessTokenCache accessTokenCache) {
    super(entityId, entityType, boxConfig, accessTokenCache);
}

private void tryRestoreUsingAccessTokenCache() {
    if (this.accessTokenCache == null) {
        // no cache specified so force authentication
        this.authenticate();
    } else {
        String cachedTokenInfo = this.accessTokenCache.get(this.getAccessTokenCacheKey());
        if (cachedTokenInfo == null) {
            // not found; probably first time for this client config so authenticate; info will then be cached
            this.authenticate();
        } else {
            // pull access token cache info; authentication will occur as needed (if token is expired)
            JsonObject json = JsonObject.readFrom(cachedTokenInfo);
            this.setAccessToken(json.get("accessToken").asString());
            this.setLastRefresh(json.get("lastRefresh").asLong());
            this.setExpires(json.get("expires").asLong());
        }
    }
}

private String getAccessTokenCacheKey() {
    return String.format("/%s/%s/%s/%s", this.getUserAgent(), this.getClientID(), this.entityType.toString(),
            this.entityID);
}

}
```